# change information on windows phone app in dev center (beta -> release, markets, pricing)

Tags: windows-phone

Since days I am trying to change my app state from beta to release so that everyone can get it.

I also figured out that I cant change other things (prince, release automatcially...)

Do I need to add a new app? Cant I change this informations by a new revision?

I am sure I am just to stupid but I am at the point to create a new app in the app center just to change this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to change an app from being a beta version to being in the public store. You must resubmit the app for it to be visible in the store and change other settings (such as price).

There is a uservoice request for this functionality that you can vote on at http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/4548415-allow-beta-to-release